# How to get output into oracle console from java code of oracle?

Tags: java, oracle

Please check Java code of Oracle. I like to get the println() output into oracle console like DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE().

I have also created a function/procedure (without return in java) to call the java function. it executed fine and return the value (for function), BUT don't print anything into Oracle console (ServerOutput).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Azam/Azam_Test" as package Azam;

import java.lang.*;
public class Azam_Test {

    public static String Azam_Test_Print(String testString) {
      System.out.println(testString); // want this output into ORACLE console
      return testString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working full script.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CALL dbms_java.set_output(2000);

Call completed.

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "MyOutput" as
  2  
  3  import java.lang.*;
  4  public class MyOutput {
  5  
  6      public static String print(String testString) {
  7        System.out.println(testString); // want this output into ORACLE console
  8        return testString;
  9      }
 10  }
 11  /

Java Source MyOutput created

SQL> 
SQL> create or replace procedure Test_Output(testString in varchar2)
  2  as LANGUAGE JAVA
  3  NAME 'MyOutput.print(java.lang.String)';
  4  /

Procedure TEST_OUTPUT compiled

SQL> 
SQL> exec Test_Output('Hello');
Hello


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [DBMS_JAVA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/appendixa.htm#JJDEV13000) 
and procedure 
`DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(2000000)`

Check also `DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT_TO_SQL`, it is more useful